# How to pass a function into children(siblings) components in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. I want to click an image and then go to dropdown component, and then every time when I switch the selection for language, it will output a different language in console in playlist component.

Playlist component and dropdown component are siblings. How should I achieve that? I try to pass a function to dropdown component, but nothing happen.

**Parent: entry.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
 import mind_zebra from '../../images/MindScribe-zebra.png';
 import Dropdown from './Dropdown/Dropdown.js';

 export default class Entry extends React.Component {
     constructor (props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
      value : "1",
      hideZebraPic : false,
     }

     this.changeLanguage = this.changeLanguage.bind(this);
    }

     onClickHandler = () => {
     this.setState( prev => ({ hideZebraPic: !prev.hideZebraPic}));
    };

     changeLanguage (event) {
     console.log("hello");
     this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.hideZebraPic) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Dropdown langueageSelection={this.changeLanguage}/>
        </div>
    );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <img src={mind_zebra} onClick={this.onClickHandler} className="MindZebraPic" alt="zebra"/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**one child: dropdown component**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Dropdown extends React.Component {

  changeLanguage(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    console.log("hello");
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form >
        <label>
          <div className="langueageSelection">
            <select onChange={this.handleChange}>

              <option value=""> Please select a language </option>
              <option value="1"> English </option>
              <option value="2"> Chinese </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**A second child: Playlist component**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Playlist extends React.Component {

  render() {
    if (this.props.langueageSelection === "1"){
      console.log("English");

    }
    else if(this.props.langueageSelection === "2"){
      console.log("Chinese");
    }
    return (
      <div> Hi</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your <Playlist /> in the <Entry /> component?

Comment: Oh sorry. I haven’t added yet because I think if I don’t have  <Dropdown /> done, then I can’t adde <Playlist />. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first in dropdown component you are using this.setState but theres no state.

Use a getter function in Entry component.

```
 this.state = {
      value : "1",
      hideZebraPic : false,
      Language:'',
     }

getLanguage = (language) => this.setState({Language:language})
```

pass the function getLanguage down as a prop to dropdown.

in your render do this

```
<Dropdown getLanguage={this.getLanguage}/>
```

Now in dropdown component

```
 <select onChange={(e) => this.props.getLanguage(e.target.value)}>
              <option value=""> Please select a language </option>
              <option value="1"> English </option>
              <option value="2"> Chinese </option>
            </select>
```

Now you can use this.props.Language anywhere if you pass it down as a prop to a component inside of entry.

What you need to figure out is when you want to render the playlist component.

Comment: Sorry for taking this long to reply. Got a busy schedule lately. Now, I'm thinking if the user select the english, then it will load english audio, even after that if the user select the Chinese, it will load Chinese. In order to achieve that, I think I should import Playlist to Dropdown component and catch the option value by doing <Playlist value={this.props.Language}/> under the select tag, am I correct?

Comment: Thats doable, i do not know the exact structure and what your app looks like but nothing about what you said seems wrong and no worries.

Comment: But I’m not really sure how to do it. I looked it up how to communicate between siblings, but still have no clue.. do you have any idea ? My app is kind of simple. Click an image to see the dropdown of language, select one language and start loading that language of audios. And I will make a play button and a restart button